# Return collection of model from paginate?

Tags: laravel

When I do

`User::select('id')->get()`

It returns a collection.

When I do:

`User::select('id')->paginate(10)->items()`

It returns an array.

Is there any method that returns the underlying collection of the model and not an array?

Note, I'm aware of `collect(User::select('id')->paginate(10)->items())`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method [getCollection](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.html#method_getCollection) witch is earned from [AbstractPaginator](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.html)

```
$userscollection=User::select('id')->paginate(10)->getCollection();
```

now `$userscollection` will be the underling collection you want.